# How to get communes boundaries of Europe?

Tags: geospatial, city, europe

I am looking for an up-to-date **communes administrative boundraries** (LAU) of several countries in Europe (France + adjacent countries). I need it to be quite precise (less than 5m), since I intend to use it to retrieve commune names from a point (bus stop). I was thinking about OpenStreetMap and Overpass Turbo, but the coverage seems to be too wide to be processed, even country by country, here is one of my resquest :

```
[out:xml][timeout:600]; (
  area['admin_level'='2']['name'='France'];
  rel['boundary'='administrative']['admin_level'='8'](area);
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

I also found :

- [[something interesting]](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/communes#communes13) on the [eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/main/home) website, but it is from 2013 ...
- [[Official LAU]](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/lau), but it not precise enough for my needs
- [[GDAM data]](https://www.gadm.org/download_country_v3.html), but again, not precise enough

Comment: You might look at geonames.org which only lists points, not polygons, but that data, while "precise", may not be accurate.

Comment: Nuts3 from eurostat